# POSIX Shared memory vs Dynamic Link Libraries/objects in C

Tags: c, dll, shared-memory, dlopen

I'm teaching myself C and I'm beginning to realize that my instructor is not the best ;-)

Using GCC on Linux.

I'm developing a Time Series Database for collecting IOT data that's designed to run on computers with limited resources (Pi zeros, etc).
I want to be able to use multiple data collectors feeding a single database, and I want to be able to add/remove data collectors on the fly.

Originally I wrote it to use dlopen() to load libraries based on a config file. To change libraries I just update the config file and then send the main program a SIGUSER2 to tell it to reload.
So far this seems to be working ok.

I decided that I want to be able to share the data in real time with other applications, so after comparing the different types of IPC I decided to use POSIX style shared memory.
If I understand this correctly, even if I use a relatively small structure (say 60 bytes) in shared memory, it will allocate 1 page (4k) of memory?

Assuming this is correct, it occurs to me that I might be better off using shared memory to communicate with the data collectors and run them as separate programs. I could pre-assign separate variable arrays inside the structure for each data collector and then have the main application signal them in turn to allow them to write to SHM.
Aside from making the main application code simpler, this would also isolate it somewhat from the data collectors.  If one of them crashed it wouldn't stop the main application.  The data collectors could start and stop at any time without having to reload the main application.  Plus, because it's shared memory, other applications could read the data from the collectors in real time.

Questions:
I think this will use fewer resources since I wouldn't need to use dlopen() anymore, does that seem right?

Does anyone see any significant problems with this idea?

Most importantly, am I correct in assuming that any application can read(assuming the reads are atomic) from shared memory at any time without having to coordinate it?

Comment: if you choose shared memory, you must add synchronization mechanisms (semaphores, mutex, ..) to manage concurrent read/write access. Otherwise, you risk having data inconsistency in shared memory buffers.

Comment: Other IPS mechanisms might be easier, such as message queues.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the use of shared memory and implement your modules as different processes is not related with the problem of making them shared objects to be loaded initially, based on a configuration file.

The use of dynamic modules allows you to load/unload those modules at runtime, so that's a good idea for pieces of code that will be loaded or retired at runtime (e.g. if you decide to start using a new version of that IoT protocol, and you don't want to stop others from that.

once resolved the possibilities that you have with usin dynamically loadable modules, let's go to the other problem:

If each module is part of a single application and you have defined correctly the api they will use, how to register a module and start using it, and they share the same virtual space (the same data memory) the best solution, perhaps is not recurring to shared memory, queues or the like.  Most probably the best solution is to thing multithreading and have all threads running in a single process.  This will make automatically the process memory shared by all threads, and thread libraries normally have a set of different locking systems to control the blocking of resources so no thread breaks the data other thread is using.

A good example of library is the POSIX threads library (`libpthread`) which implements all locking mechanisms as mutex, condition variables, semaphores, and the like.

To use both things together, you can define a registration api to allow a main thread to load (`dlopen`) a shared executable, compiled separately, and begin data acquisition in a separate thread, while other threads work on different parts of your database.  You can define even different kind of modules, one for CoAP, another for M2M, another for opc-ua, and other to asynchronously dump all your memory data into a sql database, as an example of the things you can do.  If you structure it well, you can get a very fine approach that works fine in small devices like Raspberry or smaller.